# After creating a postgresql container with docker, I cannot log into postgresql on the computer

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers, database-connection

I installed Postgresql on my computer with Docker desktop and ran it by creating a container. Afterwards, I could not access the Postgresql databases on my computer and started receiving the "connection timeout expired" error.

I was hoping that if I deleted the container I created, I would solve this problem. But I kept getting the same error. Does anyone have a solution suggestion?